# Proof that rationals are normal in the reals: $(\mathbb{Q}, +) \trianglelefteq (\mathbb{R}, +)$

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, normal-subgroups

While reading about Vitali sets I stubled onto the fact that the rational numbers are a normal subgroup of the real numbers (with respect to $+$).
I searched for a while but could not come up with an idea how to proof this and how to describe $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$ with a corresponding homomorphism that sends $\mathbb{Q}$ to $0$.

Can someone help me out with an homomorphism or sources/links dealing with this question (on an undergraduate level).
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ has a nicer description than just that. Simply form the quotient group, and then the quotient homomorphism will have $\mathbb Q$ as a kernel. It doesn't have an obvious nice description the way, say, $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ does.

Comment: You get normality automatically because the group is abelian

Comment: Then how do I see that $\mathbb{Q}$ is normal in $\mathbb{R}$, ie. this quotient group makes any sense? @MPW Okay I see, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ALL subgroups of an abelian group are normal.

Comment: Ah of course. From the comments on my question, I take it does not exist a nice explicit homomorphism?

Comment: Nope, not much better you can get than just writing down the definition of the quotient map $q: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb R/\mathbb Z \cong S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z|=1 \}$ via $t \mapsto e^{2\pi it}$.

Under this map, $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z \cong \operatorname{tor} S^1$, the torsion subgroup of $S^1$.

So, $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q \cong (\mathbb R/\mathbb Z) / (\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$ is bound to be *very* complicated.